# Chrome extension popup page scroll not working on mac os

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-extension, es6-class

I'm building a chrome extension that shows some info in the popup window.
The elements that should show are created from a javascript module (HTMLElement) when the window opens.

**The problem** is that on Mac OS the window is not scrollable even though the elements are added to the document and its height is updated correctly.

It works as expected on Windows. Haven't tested it on Linux.

I've created a demo to highlight this issue:
https://github.com/DragosN/scroll-demo

Comment: reported bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1161137

Answer (score 3):

I have the same bug and found a good workaround :

The bug appear only on mac, when you fix the body (or other wrapper element) height or min-height to a static value. If you add an element which increases the body height, the scroll will not be triggered and the overflowing content which will be hidden.

So, the idea is to trigger the scroll with :

```css
body {
   min-height: 601px; /* the max popup height is 600px, after a scroll is applied */
}
```

and after that you need to remove the extra height if you don't want to get a useless scroll on your extension when the real height of your content is < 601px. You can do it in javascript when the view has been rendered at least one time :

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.minHeight = '600px';
```